# Windows 10 claims no Internet available, but it does work

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, wireless-networking

I have the issue that windows keeps saying that I would not have internet, and some applications won't run (for example spotify or discord). But I have an inernet connection, in fact I'm writing this on my windows computer. (Gaming and browsing the web works fine)

**Possible Reasons**

1. My routing table might be wrong

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.2     25
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.44.1    192.168.44.95     10
```

I am accessing the internet via the second route. The first one is just for my home network

2. It might be related to this specific wifi

It works when connecting to a different wifi internet network.

I need it to work when connected to a hotspot with a login. When connecting to a hotspot made by my smartphone, everything works instantly. (The table looks pretty similar, just different gateway and interface IP).

---

I think the network destination of the first route should be changed to `192.168.1.0`, is this correct and the netmask to `255.255.255.0`?  How do I do that?

But I think this is not the issue, because different networks do work. What could be wrong?

Comment: What are you using as the DNS server? Try changing to `8.8.4.4` which is Google's public DNS server.

Comment: I did that. I followed [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/windows-shows-no-internet-access-but-my-internet/2e9b593f-c31c-4448-b5d9-6e6b2bd8560c)

Comment: What's the OS version of your Windows 10? If the Microsoft 365 applications such as Outlook was affected？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following steps.

**(1) DISM and SFC**

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator

dism.exe /online  /cleanup-image  /startcomponentcleanup

dism.exe /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth

SFC /SCANNOW

Restart and then:

**(2)  TCP/IP Reset**

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator

Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt

Then: ipconfig /flushdns

Then: restart the computer

After all the above, test and please let us know.

If the above does not work, then:

**(3) Windows 10 Repair Install**

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

If the Repair will not run as per above, use the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key, then run Setup on the USB Key.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Start with the option to Keep Everything.

Comment: Still the same... Connecting to my phone does work, when connected to the hotspot with the login it won't. The metrics are wrong again, my local network is higher than the network with internet.

Comment: I use dual boot with ubuntu. Maybe this has an effect?

Comment: I amended my answer to include a Windows 10 Repair Install which is the remaining step before reinstalling windows

Comment: Ubuntu on a different boot disk should not affect the error you see. It might, but I should not think so.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Yesterday it worked, now it does not. I will do a repair tomorrow and let you know

Comment: I just now booted into Windows and everything seems to be fine. I did nothing at all. Let's see... Thank you anyway

Comment: I think the repairs I outlined may have taken effect.